# Dart source code for basic mathematical functions

Tags: dart, math, implementation

Just out of interest I recently tried to take a look at the source code of some basic mathematical functions in the dart programming language (more specifically, in the `dart:math` package).

Take e.g. the cosine function. It was easy enough to find its documentation

[Cosine documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.2.6/dart-math/cos.html)

and click on the 'View source code' button in the top right corner. However, here the problems begin. In the respective file, the only related line of code is

```
/// Converts [radians] to a [double] and returns the cosine of the value.
///
/// If [radians] is not a finite number, the result is NaN.
external double cos(num radians);
```

with no hint whatsoever where to find the actual implementation. In fact, it seems that it is not at all contained in the `sdk/lib/math` directory as one might expect.

Has anyone an idea where to find it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It probably is using the libc or libm implementation.

Comment: They call libm or equivalent. The only things implemented in dart are random number generator, rectangle and point. https://dart.googlesource.com/sdk//+/c267586b652c0101a3f54ef7a75a08c0be27dafb/sdk/lib/math?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a developer on the Dart project so I might get all of this wrong. So see my answer here as my best guess into what is going on. :)

When running native, Dart uses the libc version of `cos`. The implementation are a bit tricky to find but let's try do an attempt. The definition you have found are defined as `external` which means the actual implementation are getting patched in depending on the running platform.

So for native, we need to look at:

```dart
@pragma("vm:exact-result-type", "dart:core#_Double")
@pragma("vm:prefer-inline")
double cos(num radians) => _cos(radians.toDouble());
...
@pragma("vm:recognized", "other")
@pragma("vm:prefer-inline")
external double _cos(double x);
```

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/3b128c5454834a1aaef37d9bb12595e7c217ab61/sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/math_patch.dart#L133-L135

The hint here is `vm:recognized` which tells the Dart compiler that it should handle this method call special. We can in the SDK find a list of methods it should recognize for special handling. And here we find:

```
// (class-name, function-name, recognized enum, fingerprint).
// When adding a new function, add a 0 as the fingerprint and run the build in
// debug mode to get the correct fingerprint from the mismatch error.
...
  V(::, _sin, MathSin, 0x17cc3e23)                                             \
  V(::, _cos, MathCos, 0xf485f165)                                             \
  V(::, _tan, MathTan, 0xeb0bc957)                                             \
  V(::, _asin, MathAsin, 0x29d649be)                                           \
  V(::, _acos, MathAcos, 0x1ffc14fb)                                           \
  V(::, _atan, MathAtan, 0x10ebd512)                                           \
  V(::, _atan2, MathAtan2, 0x58c66573)                                         \
  V(::, _sqrt, MathSqrt, 0x0309a7b0)                                           \
  V(::, _exp, MathExp, 0x00e673f0)                                             \
  V(::, _log, MathLog, 0x099ff882)                                             \
...
```

We can then later find trace of `MathCos` in `il.cc`:

```cpp
const RuntimeEntry& InvokeMathCFunctionInstr::TargetFunction() const {
  switch (recognized_kind_) {
    case MethodRecognizer::kDoubleTruncateToDouble:
      return kLibcTruncRuntimeEntry;
    case MethodRecognizer::kDoubleRoundToDouble:
      return kLibcRoundRuntimeEntry;
    case MethodRecognizer::kDoubleFloorToDouble:
      return kLibcFloorRuntimeEntry;
    case MethodRecognizer::kDoubleCeilToDouble:
      return kLibcCeilRuntimeEntry;
    case MethodRecognizer::kMathDoublePow:
      return kLibcPowRuntimeEntry;
    case MethodRecognizer::kDoubleMod:
      return kDartModuloRuntimeEntry;
    case MethodRecognizer::kMathTan:
      return kLibcTanRuntimeEntry;
    case MethodRecognizer::kMathAsin:
      return kLibcAsinRuntimeEntry;
    case MethodRecognizer::kMathSin:
      return kLibcSinRuntimeEntry;
    case MethodRecognizer::kMathCos:
      return kLibcCosRuntimeEntry;
    case MethodRecognizer::kMathAcos:
      return kLibcAcosRuntimeEntry;
    case MethodRecognizer::kMathAtan:
      return kLibcAtanRuntimeEntry;
    case MethodRecognizer::kMathAtan2:
      return kLibcAtan2RuntimeEntry;
    case MethodRecognizer::kMathExp:
      return kLibcExpRuntimeEntry;
    case MethodRecognizer::kMathLog:
      return kLibcLogRuntimeEntry;
    default:
      UNREACHABLE();
  }
  return kLibcPowRuntimeEntry;
}
```

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/3b128c5454834a1aaef37d9bb12595e7c217ab61/runtime/vm/compiler/backend/il.cc#L6991-L7027

The name of this constant kinda gives away that we are using libc. But finding the definition of `kLibcCosRuntimeEntry` is not obvious since this constant are getting generated using the following macro:

```
#define DEFINE_RAW_LEAF_RUNTIME_ENTRY(name, argument_count, is_float, func)    \
  extern const RuntimeEntry k##name##RuntimeEntry(                             \
      "DFLRT_" #name, func, argument_count, true, is_float,                    \
      /*can_lazy_deopt=*/false)
```

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/3b128c5454834a1aaef37d9bb12595e7c217ab61/runtime/vm/runtime_entry.h#L147-L150

And is then used here:

```cpp
DEFINE_RAW_LEAF_RUNTIME_ENTRY(
    LibcCos,
    1,
    true /* is_float */,
    reinterpret_cast<RuntimeFunction>(static_cast<UnaryMathCFunction>(&cos)));
```

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/3b128c5454834a1aaef37d9bb12595e7c217ab61/runtime/vm/runtime_entry.cc#L3894-L3898

Where `&cos` refer to the `cos` method that have been globally imported from `math.h` here:

```
#include <math.h>
```

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/3b128c5454834a1aaef37d9bb12595e7c217ab61/runtime/platform/globals.h#L83

Comment: Thanks a lot for really working out where to look, I definitely wouldn't have been able to do that myself. So, do I understand correctly that on compile-time the compiler either translates the dart code to javascript or "really" compiles the code while replacing the math functions with their implementations in c?

Comment: @junjios The Dart compiler have multiple targets e.g. different CPU architectures, different operating systems and then also JavaScript (and soon WASM). For some of those choices, the compiler can choose different ways to implement parts of the SDK so we get the most optimal solution. E.g. on JavaScript, we will benefit using methods which the browser gives access to since those are more efficient and will make our code shorter. Similar when target native, it makes sense to utilize functionality from standard libs which we already have imported in the native runtime like e.g. libc.